# Processing is adding slashes and arrows to the end of lines after autoformat

Tags: java, processing

I did a quick search but I couldn't find anything relevant. Whenever I autoformat (ctrl+t) a file in processing ide, if I open the same file in vscode, some of the lines have `//<>//` at the end

[a video of this happening](https://youtu.be/pqymjGB6Eh8)

[image: image of vscode]
[image: image of processing ide]

Comment: I though I would never, ever say this, but I think that you should post this on Processing's forum. It's very interesting btw, don't forget to post your answer here if you find it elsewhere.

Comment: I realize you're just following instructions, but please link between crossposts so we can see what other help you've already received. This has been posted in the Processing forum [here](https://discourse.processing.org/t/processing-is-adding-slashes-and-arrows-to-the-end-of-lines-after-autoformat/20949).

Comment: Seems something worth [filling an issue on github](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues)

Comment: I added a link to a video I made of this happening. I was going to add the link to the post on the processing forum but it said "new users can only have one image in a post" and since it's already up with both images, I'm only going to add the video here